# Ways to declare object in c#

Tags: c#, object

I have learned C# for a little bit, and there's one part that make me confused. It is how can we declare objects.  I usually declare objects using `FormGame frm = new FormGame()`, but i found that there are more of it.

These are the examples:

```cs
var frm = new FormClothes();

Excel._Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
```

Can you guys explain the difference, name of the technique and how it works? You can add more examples of ways declaring object, it will be helpful for me and other learners.

Maybe, some of u may hard to understand what i mean with 'name of the technique'. So, ill try to explain it. For example : `new AddRecord()`. I name it as "calling class without declaring object". U can do it if u add static infront of access modifier (public static .....).

Comment: In the first example you are *initialising* a new object with the `new` keyword, in the second, you are just referencing an existing object and casting

Comment: Be aware that you shouldn't use the `[visual-studio]` tag for questions that aren't about the Visual Studio _application_.

Comment: `frm` and `worksheet` both hold references to an object of their respective types. It's just that in the first instance you're assigning the reference of a new object to it and in the second you're assigning an existing reference value (i.e. `excelApp.ActiveSheet` and `worksheet` both reference the same object in memory).

Comment: [new operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator) and [Casting and type conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) and [Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

Comment: There is no big difference between `var frm = new FormClothes();` and `FormGame frm = new FormGame()`. `var` is implicit and `FormGame` is explicit.

Comment: you can call a method, not a class, so `new AddRecord()` is "calling default constructor of `AddRecord` class" and it has nothing to do with `static` modifier. You need to learn a lot more of `C#`

Comment: Your main issue is **terminology**. You don't declare objects you declare **variables**. `var frm = new FormClothes();` declares a `frm` variable and then instantiates (creates) an instance of `FormClothes` and **assigns** it to the variable. `Excel._Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;` declares a `worksheet` variable and then **casts** `excelApp.ActiveSheet` to `Excel.Worksheet` and assigns the result of the cast to `worksheet`.

Answer (score 4):

We don't really use the phrase "declare object".  It would be more common to talk of "declaring a variable":

```
FormGame f;
```

That declares a variable called `f` that is capable of holding an object instance of type FormGame or one of its descendants.

`var` is nothing special - it's just an instruction to the compiler "I want you to work out what type of object is being assigned and automatically make the f variable that type". To work it out there needs to be an assignment. You cannot say:

```
var f;
```

It has to have something on the right so the compiler can guess the type:

```
var f = new FormGame();
```

You should try to use var only when it i obvious to the human reading the code (which may not be you) what type of object is being created. These are good and cut down clutter:

```
var formattedStr = something.ToString();
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

This is ok:

```
var s = "a string";
```

This is perhaps not so good:

```
var res = process.GetResult();
```

Intellisense and visual studio will be able to work it out, which is why you see var everywhere and overused, but it usually makes code more readable and faster to understand if we can read/know the type without having to point to something in visual studio and wait for a tooltip to tell us what type it is

Sometimes var lets you down, and `var`'ing a declaration means you end up with a guess at the type that is way up in the inheritance hierarchy. For example `r` here is guessed as type `object`, the base of all things in c#, and this makes the code pretty unusable without casting:

```
foreach(var r in dataTable.Rows)
```

If we are specific, it works ok:

```
foreach(DataRow r in dataTable.Rows)
```

---

We talk of "creating an object" or "creating an instance" when we use the `new` keyword. We usually assign the instance to a variable, but not always:

```
f = new FormGame(); //make a new instance and assign to a previously declared variable
```

We don't have to assign to a variable:

```
new FormGame().ShowDialog();
```

This will make a new instance of a FormGame and show it, but we then have no way of reaching the object to do anything else with it - it is lost after this one line of code

We don't have to use the `new` keyword to give a variable a value:

```
f = otherForm;
```

This assigns a value, but we haven't created any new object here, we've just pointed `f` at the same object in memory that our `otherForm` is pointing to. If you change one thing about the object using variable f, the other variable sees the change too:

```
otherForm.Text = "Hello"; 
MessageBox.Show(f.Text); //shows Hello
```

Your example of assigning an excel sheet variable is also of this form; it's  not making any new thing, it's taking an existing thing and assigning it to a variable. In your case there's is a cast involved but casting doesn't create a new object, it changes the apparent type of an existing object. I say *apparent* type because it doesn't change the actual type of an object, only how it appears. A string will always be a string and cannot be cast to an int:

```
string s = "123";
int x = (int)s; // no
```

But because string is descended from object it can be assigned to a variable of type object:

```
object o = s; // works ok
```

To get the string back out you have to go from something that looks like a parent type, to the child type and that requires a cast:

```
string t = (string)o; //only works if o really is holding a string or a descendant of string
```

None of this assigning is making a new object - it's the same "123" going round and round even if it's cast

---

When it comes to creating object instances, your code might not use `new`, but the code you use probably does

```
SomeClass x = classFactory.Create();
```

Here we have an object whose job is to manufacture new objects. We didn't use the `new` keyword in our code, but the class factory probably did. We also did the declaring if variable x and assigning the value of x all in one line. This pattern of code is something you may come across, particularly with reflection, where you're asking another class to create a new instance for you rather than using new. It can help to have a method or property Male a new thing so you can get some info about what it is you're creating. If we think about the datetime for a moment:

```
DateTime x = DateTime.Now;
DateTime y = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Here this uses statics (which I'll come to in a moment) and named properties to manufacture objects. Calling Now will create a datetime that is the current time in the local time zone. Calling UtcNow creates a datetime that is the current time in UTC. Microsoft could surely have made it so that you had to do this:

```
DateTime x = new DateTime(DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTime y = new DateTime(DateTimeKind.Universal);
```

But it's pretty wordy and needs the developer to remember "when I use the constructor that takes a DateTimeKind parameter, the returned datetime will be the current time"

All in, using these convenience properties called Now and UtcNow manufacture new objects for us and they tell us succinctly and explicitly what kind of thing they created

---

static is slightly different. It's perhaps best thought of as a scenario where the compiler invisibly does new for you and assigns it to a global variable with the same name as the class

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
```

This declares a datetime variable called d. It accesses the  Now property of DateTime statically - this means you don't need to have made a new datetime before you can call on the Now property.

If you struggle to understand statics, imagine that somewhere there is one instance of a DateTime object, and it is called DateTime. It is "created invisibly" and "accessible from everywhere". Imagine that the compiler writes something like this for you:

```
global DateTime DateTime = new DateTime();
```

It doesn't actually happen this way of course, but thinking of it like this might help you understand statics; imagine that that line of code happens somewhere where you can't see